# How to create a playlist in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, embed

I need to create a playlist and run it. I also need to inform seconds that the music will play.

i'm using arrays for this:

```
var listMusic = ["hs.wav", "gs.wav"];
var musicDuration = ["10", "20"];
```

How must play all songs in the list, I use one FOR to that:

```
for(i = 0; i < listMusic.length; i++)
{
    var music = listMusic[i];
    setInterval(function() {playSound("'" + music + "'");}, musicDuration[i] * 1000);
}
```

this is my function playSound():

```
function playSound(music){
document.getElementById("span_alerta").innerHTML = "<embed src='" + music + "' hidden=false autostart=true loop=false playcount=3>";
```

}

Thus, he is just playing the last song of the array. This happens because the LOOP performs twice while I'm waiting for the 10 seconds

Anyone know how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you may find a lot of libraries to handle this stuff. Anyway you could modify your code in a recursive function

```
var index=-1;
function playNext() {
    index++;
    var music = listMusic[i];
    if (music) {
        playSound("'" + music + "'");
        setInterval('playNext', musicDuration[index] * 1000);
    }
}
```